# How do open world games handle efficiently enemy respawn?

Tags: architecture, design-patterns, memory-efficiency, memory, spawning

I'm currently working on a 2D open world game loaded in chunks, initially I thought It would be sufficient to spawn entities randomly in a specific "radius" close to the player, and periodically remove distant enemies.

Though appealing, this system is inefficient unless you keep in memory the chunks surrounding the chunk the player is in (if an enemy needs to spawn on a chunk which is currently not in memory, you have no way of knowing wether you can actually place it in a specific tile or not, since it may be occluded by a wall) which is why I'm currently spawning enemies as soon as chunks are loaded, but there's a problem..

A massive complication arises when enemies are spawned with specific criteria. Assume a little dungeon spawns inside a chunk, it needs 2 enemies and a chest with loot in-between them. When you're done with it, it shouldn't respawn unless an hour passed. You can't just spawn those enemies inside the structure as soon as it's close enough to the player, otherwise you could go back 'n fort, kill the enemies and keep looting the chest's content.

Time to make a cache right? Let's forget for a moment any complication related to how you could make it memory efficient, and analyze this particular scenario:

- The player enters a chunk with said structure
- Enemies and chests are then spawned
- A cache marks this particular dungeon as "already spawned, check back in an hour"
- Instead of getting closer to the dungeon, the player moves in the opposite direction, until the dungeon gets out of view and enemies are removed since they're now too distant
- ..few minutes later, the player goes back where the dungeon is, only to find an empty dungeon because the structure was marked as "already spawned" and wont spawn again unless an hour is passed.

I thought about caching all enemies that where present inside a chunk when it gets out of view and restoring them as soon as the chunk is visible again, yet again this requires caching every entity inside a chunk and keep the entry available for an hour, and periodically check if in that particular chunk an hour is passed and we can spawn again enemies

Doesn't look too bad, but if a player moves in a straight line in my game for an hour I would need to cache about 200 chunks before cache entries start expiring!

Is there a better solution? How do modern games handle enemies spawn? How do they get around these difficulties? I'm particularly interested in knowing how online games do it considering the crazy amount of memory (which should be shared between servers) such systems may require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to persist the state of a chunk but you are running out of memory, consider persisting it to the hard drive. If your game has enough complexity and data to warrant it, you might want to consider to use an embedded SQL database like SQLite for this purpose.

However, I doubt that this is even necessary for your game. How much data do you really need to keep in memory for an enemy in an inactive chunk? You don't need to render it, so any visual data (mesh, animation state...) can be unloaded. You don't need to update it, so its AI state is likely irrelevant, too.

So what's left to persist?

Position? 3 floating point numbers. Rotation? Between 1 and 4 floating point numbers, depending on how you handle it. Game mechanical values? A couple integers. I would be surprised if you manage to come over a few hundred bytes per entity. But let's be generous and assume a full KB of data. So one GB of memory could store up to a million inactive entities.

Comment: Thanks for your input, you're right with a few calculations I'd be using at max 200kb for 400 chunks worth of enemies, though I still don't know how to solve the problem of "zombie dungeons" described in the question, which is my current bottleneck

Comment: @RowRebel I don't see the problem. 1. When the player visits a dungeon for the first time, the entities in it are spawned. 2. When the player leaves, the entities get deactivated. 3. When the player returns, the inactive entities in it get reactivated. Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Right I somehow managed to forgot my own initial solution, it was a long day thanks again